# How do i check my app's frame rate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to find out the frame rate of my iOS app, i'm wondering how to check that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to profile your app with Instruments and use the Core Animation instrument. IIRC it should give frame rate.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use SpriteKit's SKView!

```
SKView *skView = [[SKView alloc] init];
skView.frame = CGRectMake(240, 525, 60, 15);
skView.showsFPS = YES;
[self.view addSubview:skView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count your created frames after each rendering steps and take the runtime between them. So you can write them to your app if you like to show the frame rate during the runtime.